# Killing several processes

Tags: command-line, process, kill

I have one command (`/usr/lib/R/exec/R pathtoDifferentFiles`) being executed with many different arguments (file names). Looking at `htop`, I see at least 30 processes created,

I want to kill all of them at the same time.

Is there a way to kill processes that apply a command starting with a pattern? (`/usr/lib/R/exec/R`)

Comment: what's the command for a single file?

Comment: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --file=fileName --args. I have many different possible arguments (each process takes a different argument name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the `pkill` command:

```
pkill --full /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

From the `pkill` man page:

> ```
> pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process.
>
> [...]
>
>       -f, --full
>         The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.
>         When -f is set, the full command line is
>         used.
> ```

Comment: It doesn't work. In fact, my command starts with usr/lib/R/exec/R for each process, but then each process has a different name since my script calls different arguments

Comment: Could you please attach in a http://pastebin.ubuntu.com the result of `ps -aef` with the 30 processes?

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7488331/

Answer (score 2):

Try this command,

```
ps aux | awk '/\/usr\/lib\/R\/exec\/R/ {print $2}' | xargs kill
```

OR

```
pa aux | awk '/\/usr\/lib\/R\/bin\/exec\/R/ {print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: Because in your question, you mentioned `/usr/lib/R/exec/R` but in your comment you mentioned `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R`

Comment: got: unexpected character '\'

Comment: please post the command you tried along with the output in pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7488403/

Comment: Your command should be `pa aux | awk '/\/usr\/lib\/R\/bin\/exec\/R/ {print $2}' | xargs kill
` not `ps aux | awk '/\/usr\/lib\/R\/bin/\exec\/R\ {print $2}' | xargs kill`

Comment: Error in /bin/\exec\/R\

Comment: sorry about that http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7488439/

Comment: you still don't run the exact command which was posted by me.

Comment: Next to R it's forward slash not backward slash.

Comment: now it is working. Sorry about the typos

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
ps -ef| awk '/\/usr\/lib\/R\/bin\/exec\/R/ {print $2}' |xargs kill -9
```

Comment: How can I specify the pattern when I have different arguments names? /usr/lib/R/exec/R is common for all the processes, but then the command has different names for each process

Comment: try this command now

Comment: I get: ps -ef|awk '/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R/{print $2}' |xargs kill -9
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.

Comment: try the code now

Comment: it doesn't do anything

Comment: @teaLeef if already all the process are closed, this doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried before closing the processes

Answer (score 0):

The [killall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) command should do what you want:

```
killall /usr/lib/R/exec/R
```