# How to kill multiple processes?

Tags: kill

Is there a way to kill multiple processes? e.g.

```
kill -9 49855 49856
```

I have tried using commands like `pkill` but they require a single pattern and do not allow multiple pid inputs.

Comment: You may be looking for `killall`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Killing several processes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469089/killing-several-processes) In fact, it didn't mention `killall`, so added that there. Nor indeed does it mention @steeldriver's insight below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bash shell's builtin `kill` appears to accept only a single PID (or jobspec). However the external `kill` command (from package `procps`) accepts multiple pids:

```
$ sleep 60 & sleep 60 &
[1] 25208
[2] 25209

$ /bin/kill 25208 25209
[1]-  Terminated              sleep 60
[2]+  Terminated              sleep 60
```